# Why is wine creating "identical" directories on F23

Tags: linux, wine, fedora-23

I installed [wine](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Wine) on `Fedora 23` using packages install

```
sudo dnf install wine
sudo dnf install winetricks
```

It seems that it created many directory with same name, but as you can see not the same structure (Program Files x64 holds the apps I installed on one but not the other)

Is there an explanation or did I f*** something up ?

```
$ tree -L 3 /home/statquant/.wine
/home/statquant/.wine
├── dosdevices
│   ├── c: -> ../drive_c
│   └── z: -> /
├── drive_c
│   ├── Program\ Files
│   │   ├── Common\ Files
│   │   ├── Internet\ Explorer
│   │   ├── Windows\ Media\ Player
│   │   └── Windows\ NT
│   ├── Program\ Files\ (x86)
│   │   ├── Adobe
│   │   ├── Common\ Files
│   │   ├── ePUBee
│   │   ├── Internet\ Explorer
│   │   ├── Windows\ Media\ Player
│   │   └── Windows\ NT
│   ├── run-adobe_diged.bat
│   ├── users
│   │   ├── Public
│   │   └── statquant
│   └── windows
│       ├── command
│       ├── [LOTS OF STUFF HERE]
│       └── winsxs
├── system.reg
├── userdef.reg
├── user.reg
└── winetricks.log
```

---

```
$ tree -L 2 -d /home/statquant/drive_c/
/home/statquant/drive_c/
├── Program\ Files
│   ├── Common\ Files
│   ├── Internet\ Explorer
│   ├── Windows\ Media\ Player
│   └── Windows\ NT
├── Program\ Files\ (x86)
│   ├── Common\ Files
│   ├── Internet\ Explorer
│   ├── Windows\ Media\ Player
│   └── Windows\ NT
├── users
│   ├── Public
│   └── statquant
└── windows
    ├── command
    ├── Fonts
    ├── help
    ├── inf
    ├── Installer
    ├── logs
    ├── Microsoft.NET
    ├── mono
    ├── system
    ├── system32
    ├── syswow64
    ├── temp
    └── winsxs
```